# Numbers to English Strings in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, converting

Inspired by the recent surge of questions dealing with changing numbers to their English equivalents (See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59436/spell-a-given-number-in-english), [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39183/python-converter-number-to-english?rq=1), and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58939/naming-numbers-in-american-english)), I decided to write my own version in Python.

```
zero_to_nineteen = (
    "zero",
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
    "seven",
    "eight",
    "nine",
    "ten",
    "eleven",
    "twelve",
    "thirteen",
    "fourteen" ,
    "fifteen",
    "sixteen",
    "seventeen",
    "eighteen",
    "nineteen"
)

tens = (
    "zero",
    "ten",
    "twenty",
    "thirty",
    "forty",
    "fifty",
    "sixty",
    "seventy",
    "eighty",
    "ninety"
)

suffixes = {
    3 : "thousand",
    6 : "million",
    9 : "billion",
    12 : "trillion",
    15 : "quadrillion",
    18 : "quintillion",
    21 : "sextillion",
    24 : "septillion",
    27 : "octillion",
    30 : "nonillion",
    33 : "decillion",
    36 : "undecillion"
    39 : "duodecillion",
    42 : "tredicillion",
    45 : "quattuordecillion",
    48 : "quinquadecillion",
    51 : "sedecillion",
    54 : "septendecillion",
    57 : "octodecillion",
    60 : "novendecillion",
    63 : "vigintillion",
    66 : "unvigintillion",
    69 : "duovigintillion",
    72 : "tresvigintillion",
    75 : "quattuorvigintillion",
    78 : "quinquavigintillion",
    81 : "sesvigintillion",
    84 : "septemvigintillion",
    87 : "octovigintillion",
    90 : "novemvigintillion",
    93 : "trigintillion",
    96 : "untrigintillion",
    99 : "duotrigintillion",
    102 : "trestrigintilion",
    105 : "quattuortrigintillion",
    108 : "quinquatrigintillion",
    111 : "sestrigintillion",
    114 : "septentrigintillion",
    117 : "octotrigintillion",
    120 : "noventrigintillion",
    123 : "quadragintillion"
}

def spell_out(number):
    """Returns a string representation of the number, in english"""
    if isinstance(number, float):
        raise ValueError("number must be an integer")

    if number < 0:
        return "negative " + spell_out(-1 * number)

    if number < 20:
        return zero_to_nineteen[number]

    if number < 100:
        tens_digit = number // 10
        ones_digit = number % 10
        if ones_digit == 0:
            return tens[tens_digit]
        else:
            return "{}-{}".format(tens[tens_digit], zero_to_nineteen[ones_digit])

    if number < 1000:
        hundreds_digit = zero_to_nineteen[number // 100]
        rest = number % 100
        if rest == 0:
            return "{} hundred".format(hundreds_digit)
        else:
            return "{} hundred {}".format(hundreds_digit, spell_out(rest))

    suffix_index = log(number)
    suffix_index -= suffix_index % 3

    prefix = spell_out(number // 10 ** suffix_index)
    suffix = suffixes[suffix_index]

    rest_of_number = number % (10 ** suffix_index)

    if suffix_index in suffixes:
        if number % (10 ** suffix_index) == 0:
            return "{} {}".format(prefix, suffix)
        else:
            return "{} {} {}".format(prefix, suffix, spell_out(rest_of_number))

    return "infinity"

def log(number):
    """Returns integer which is log base 10 of number"""
    answer = 0
    while number > 9:
        answer += 1
        number //= 10
    return answer
```

I would appreciate any comments on my code.

Comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on Davidmh's answer, here are some other improvements:

### Consistency:

Instead of using tuples for only `tens` and `zero_to_nineteen`, stay consistent and use it for the `suffixes` as well, by making it 1000's based. Aka, the indices would correspond to the power of a thousand that the number relates to. For example, 1000 could be 1st element, while `10 ** 30` would be the 10th.

### Code Style:

Your code repeatedly utilizes blocks of the format:

```
a = number // x
b = number % x
```

This can be simplified down using Python's built-int `divmod` function like so:

```
a, b = divmod(number, x)
```

Also, your code repeatedly uses code segments like this:

```
if second_part == 0:
    return first_part
else:
    return first_part + separator + second_part
```

You are violating the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle by doing this and should instead abstract this logic out into a function of its own like so:

```
def _create_number(prefix, suffix, seperator=" "):
    # Returns a number with given prefix and suffix (if needed)
    if not isinstance(prefix, str):
        prefix = spell_out(prefix)
    return prefix if suffix == 0 else prefix + seperator + spell_out(suffix)
```

**Other Suggestions:**

Normally, numbers are expected to be separated by commas. So one million three hundred thousand forty-five would be one million, three hundred thousand, forty-five. This is easy to do with the suggested function, as you simply make the seperator `", "` instead of `" "`.

Instead of fumbling around with floats and such, let Python handle it via `int()` and then the only thing you would want to catch is when that throws an `OverflowError` for large floating point values (like `1e584`). This is done like so:

```
try:
    number = int(number)
except OverflowError:
    # This will be triggered if trying to use this with numbers like 1e584
    return "infinity"
```

Python will raise a `ValueError` automatically anyways if it's not something that can be interpreted by `int()`. This code also has the benefit of being a bit more future-proof. If `int()` will start to work with tuples or other data types someday (aka `(1, 2, 3)` could become 123), then this code will still work.

Lastly, you could add a special case for a thousand, and then remove the `-illion` from each of the suffixes for a more compact form.

Answer (score 4):

It looks mostly fine. I only have three comments:

- The definitions of `zero_to_nineteen` and `tens`  is too long for my taste. It will look more readable like this::

  ```
  tens = ("zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty",
          "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety")
  ```
- Reject floats straight away is too much. One cannot then ask for the spelling of `1e6`. I would do:

  ```python
  if isinstance(number, float):
       if number % 1 == 0:
           number = int(number)
       else:
           raise ValueError("number must be an integer")

  elif not isinstance(number, int):
       raise ValueError("number must be a number")
  ```

  Note that your function would happily accept things like `1j`, `"abc"`, `None`...
- For Guido's beard, don't roll your own log function! use `int(math.log10)`

Comment: @mleyfman I would extend the same comment to `suffixes`, it is still a long column of (fairly trivial) information.