# Numbers to words converter

Tags: java, beginner, converting, numbers-to-words

Please review my code:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


class NumberToWords
{
  static public boolean HelperConvertNumberToText(int num, String[] result)
  {
      String [] strones = {
        "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
        "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen",
        "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen",
      };

      String [] strtens = {
          "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty",
          "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety", "Hundred"
      };

      result[0] = "";
      int single, tens, hundreds;

      if(num > 1000)
          return false;

      hundreds = num / 100;
      num = num - hundreds * 100;
      if( num < 20)
      {
          tens = 0; // special case
          single = num;
      }
      else
      {
          tens = num / 10;
          num = num - tens * 10;
          single = num;
      }

      if(hundreds > 0)
      {
         result[0] += strones[hundreds-1];
         result[0] += " Hundred ";
      }
      if(tens > 0)
      {
         result[0] += strtens[tens - 1];
         result[0] += " ";
      }
      if(single > 0)
      {
         result[0] += strones[single - 1];
         result[0] += " ";
      }
      return true;
  }

  static public boolean ConvertNumberToText(int num, String[] result)
  {
      String tempString[] = new String[1];
      tempString[0] = "";
      int thousands;
      int temp;
      result[0] = "";
      if(num < 0 || num > 100000)
      {
          System.out.println(num + " \tNot Supported");
          return false;
      }

      if( num == 0)
      {
         System.out.println(num + " \tZero");
         return false;
      }

      if(num < 1000)
      {  
          HelperConvertNumberToText(num, tempString);
          result[0] += tempString[0];
      }
      else
      {
          thousands = num / 1000;
          temp = num - thousands * 1000;
          HelperConvertNumberToText(thousands, tempString);
          result[0] += tempString[0];
          result[0] += "Thousand ";             
          HelperConvertNumberToText(temp, tempString);
          result[0] += tempString[0];
      }
      return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      String [] result = new String[1];
      result[0] = "";
      int  i, num;
      int [] arrNum =
      {
        -1, 0, 5, 10, 15, 19, 20, 21, 25, 33, 49, 50, 72,
        99, 100, 101, 117, 199, 200, 214, 517, 589, 999,
        1000, 1010, 1018, 1200, 9890, 10119, 13535, 57019,
        99999, 100000, 100001
      };

      for (i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++)
      {
          num = arrNum[i];
          if( ConvertNumberToText(num, result) == true)
             System.out.println(num  + "\t" + result[0]);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

"Strone"?  What's a "strone"?  Oh… [of course](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strone)!

In seriousness, naming could be improved.  They are obviously arrays of strings; the Hungarian prefix is unnecessary.  Also, as constants, they should be declared `static final` and named with `ALL_CAPS`.

```
public class NumberToWords {
    private static final ONES = { "One", "Two", … };
    private static final TENS = { "Ten", "Twenty", … };
    …
}
```

Helper functions should be `private`.

It is customary to put the `static` keyword after the access modifier, as in `public static void main(…)`.  It is unconventional to say `static public boolean ConvertNumberToText(…)`.  Also, functions should be `namedStartingWithLowerCase()`.

Using a single-element array as a parameter so that you can pass back the result as an out-parameter is very weird.  Using a `StringBuilder` would be a bit more obvious, but still very odd.  The right approach should be to return a `String`, and throw an exception if necessary — perhaps `NumberFormatException`.  Ideally, your code should be able to handle every possible `int` input, making errors impossible.

Comment: +1 for making me laugh. [Kill the Hungarian Notation with fire!](http://www.reactiongifs.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/kill_it_with_fire.gif)

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, you have a spelling error. "Fourty" should be "Forty".

Next, You have snippets like this:

> num = num - hundreds * 100;
>
> num = num - tens * 10;
>
> temp = num - thousands * 1000;

These can be simplified using the modulo operator. The modulo operator (which is `%` in java) produces the remainder of a division. For example `1024 % 100 = 24` since 1024 divides into 100 ten times with a remainder of 24.

The snippets are then:

> num %= 100;
>
> num %= 10;
>
> temp = num % 1000;

Additionally, you have unnecessary code which can be trimmed down because the results are unused. For instance, you don't use anything from any of the imports... so don't import them.

Lastly, some general code comments:

Why are your convertToString methods... returning booleans? If the arguments are invalid, then raise an `Exception`, don't return booleans. This would also simplify your code, as it would allow you to simply append the results together. This would also eliminate the need for passing a `String[]` around.

Also the `Helper` function should really be called `ConvertLessThanThousand` indicating what it does.

This is what I came up with:

```
class NumberToWords
{
  // No need to have these in the function. Unless you really care about hiding them... But reflection can still find these
  private static final String[] ONES = {
     "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
     "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen",
     "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen",
  };

  private static final String[] TENS = {
      "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty",
      "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety", "Hundred"
  };

  public String convertLessThanThousand(int num) {

      String result = "";
      int single, tens, hundreds;

      if(num > 1000)
          return result;

      hundreds = num / 100;
      num %= 100;
      if( num < 20) {
          tens = 0;
      }
      else {
          tens = num / 10;
          num %= 10;
      }
      single = num; // Notice I moved this outside since it is duplicated in both cases

      if(hundreds > 0) {
         result += ones[hundreds-1] + " Hundred ";
      }
      if(tens > 0) {
         result += tens[tens - 1] + " ";
      }
      if(single > 0) {
         result += ones[single - 1] + " ";
      }
      return result;
  }

  public static String convertNumberToText(int num)
  {
      String tempString = "";
      int thousands;
      int temp;
      String result = "";
      if(num < 0 || num > 100000) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + num + " \tNot Supported");
      }

      if( num == 0) {
         return "" + num + " \tZero";
      }

      if(num < 1000) {  
          result += ConvertLessThanThousand(num);
      }
      else {
          thousands = num / 1000;
          temp = num % 1000;
          tempString = ConvertLessThanThousand(thousands);
          result += tempString + "Thousand ";            
          result += ConvertLessThanThousand(temp);
      }
      return result
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      int  i, num;
      int[] arrNum =
      {
        -1, 0, 5, 10, 15, 19, 20, 21, 25, 33, 49, 50, 72,
        99, 100, 101, 117, 199, 200, 214, 517, 589, 999,
        1000, 1010, 1018, 1200, 9890, 10119, 13535, 57019,
        99999, 100000, 100001
      };

      for (i = 0; i < arrNum.length; i++)
      {
          num = arrNum[i];
          
          try {
             System.out.println(num + "\t" + ConvertNumberToText(num));
          } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
              System.out.println(e.message());
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Lastly, if you are planning on expanding this to bigger and bigger numbers, I would suggest using a recursive approach, not unlike what I have implemented in Python in my question [on this same site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59837/47450).

Comment: An array `String[] result` is being used to emulate out-arguments, i.e. the array behaves similar to a pointer. If we just use a `String result` and reassign that identifier inside the function, then the value that has been passed in will not have changed (Java's functions are *not* call-by-reference). Your “fixed” code will not print out any words generated by `HelperConvertNumberToText`. As you point out in the next paragraph, the correct solution would be to *return* a string, and to throw exceptions on errors rather than returning status codes.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about Java's passing by value. Thanks, will move my suggesting to replace `String[]` down to where I suggest returning strings

Comment: @amon fixed! Had to change my answer a bit